# Python: How to display json results nicely?

Tags: python, json, python-telegram-bot

I am currently building a Telegram Bot and getting JSON response on Google Places API to return nearby locations to users. 
The json Response I get is as follows:

```
results" : [
      {
         "name" : "Golden Village Tiong Bahru",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "rating" : 4.2,
         "types" : [ "movie_theater", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "user_ratings_total" : 773
      },
      {
         "name" : "Cathay Cineplex Cineleisure Orchard",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "rating" : 4.2,
         "types" : [ "movie_theater", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
         "user_ratings_total" : 574
      }
]
```

My current code to get specific items in the dictionary

```
json.dumps([[s['name'], s['rating']] for s in object_json['results']], indent=3)
```

Current Results:

```
[
   [
      "Golden Village Tiong Bahru",
      4.2
   ],
   [
      "Cathay Cineplex Cineleisure Orchard",
      4.2
   ]
]
```

I would like to get the name and rating and display side by side instead:

```
Golden Village Tiong Bahru : 4.2, 
Cathay Cineplex Cineleisure Orchard : 4.2
```

Please help.

Comment: `for s in object_json['results']: print('%(name)s : %(rating)s' % s)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want json format as a result?
Then you can do:

```py
json.dumps({
    s['name']: s['rating']
    for s in object_json['results']
}, indent=3)
```

If you want just string list:

```py
lines = [f"{s['name']}: {s['rating']}" for s in object_json['results']]
```

Or you want to print only:

```py
for s in object_json['results']:
    print(f"{s['name']}: {s['rating']}")
```

You need 3.6 or higher python interpreter to use f-string(`f"..."`).

I you don't, replace
`f"{s['name']}: {s['rating']}"` -> `'{name}: {rating}'.format(**s)`

Comment: Thanks it works! But is it possible for non-json? just the text
Because I will have the **" "** quotation marks and some weird characters **\u2013**

```{
   "Park Hotel Alexandra": 4.3,
   "ibis budget Singapore Mount Faber (formerly known as Fragrance Hotel \u2013 Royal)": 3.6
}```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!! I tried the **for loop** it works but its only giving me the first name for the first item. i have been trying to figure out the for loop as well.

Comment: I just realized it might be because I use return instead of print

Comment: Hi just wondering, if in the key-value pair, the value is in list, is it possible remove the underscore?? now my results is **Local Restaurant & Bar: restaurant, food, _point_of_interest_, establishment**. thanks for your help

Comment: @blueKingdom11 You can call `str.replace` method for that. For example, `s['rating'].replace('_', ' ')`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with:

```
json.dumps([s['name'] + ": " + str(s['rating']) for s in object_json['results']], indent=3)
```